# kendo hierarchy doesn't show the data of details grid for the second time clicking

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've used the hierarchical kendo for showing my data, I mean each row has a child which contains a grid of rows' details,my kendo should appear based on the data that user enter in inputs and after click on a button , it works well for the first time but if user change the inputs' data and click the button again, the kendo does not show the grid of details it just show me my parent grid but if the user refresh the page and then change the data and click the button it works fine. after a lot of search I couldn't find the reason.can anyone help me

```
var grid;
var createGrid = function () {
    grid = $("#mygrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: schema.PNR_item,
            schema: {
                hasChildren: true,
                model:{
                    fields:fields,
                }
            },
            pageable: true,
            height: 550,
            pageSize: 6,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            //columns
        },
        height: 600,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        resizable:true,
        columns: columns,
        detailTemplate: '<div class="grid" ></div>',
        detailInit: function (e) {
            e.detailRow.find(".grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: e.data.Details,
                columns: details_columns,
                schema:{
                    model:{
                        fields: details_fields
                    }
                }
            });
        },
    }).data("kendoGrid");
}//end of createGrid function
createGrid();
```

Comment: Can anyone help me or suggest me some solutions?

Comment: I understood when I change the inputs value and click the button again my tr with k-detail-row class get display:none by inline style and I don't know why. but it get the value from the source it just does not display.

Comment: I solved it by adding this code to detailInit function.

  e.detailRow.kendoGrid.css({ display: "table-row" })

Comment: I've faced with new problem, now when I choose each record to show the detailsGrid information, it scrolls to the top of the page and it doesn't look good.can anyone help me?